# How to I make one column from multiple lists?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Whenever I post the following code the output is a group of lists, but how do I organize them into just one column?

```
# Import libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Get URL and extract content
class Scraper():
page=1
traits = []
while page != 10:
    content = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/recklesslabs/wickedcraniums/main/{}'.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')
    page = page + 1
    
    dic_list = list(map(eval, soup))
    for dic in dic_list:
        traits = dic["attributes"]

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(traits, orient='columns').to_numpy()
    df1 = list(np.concatenate(df[0:1]))
    
    print(df1)
```

When I use the code above I get this output:

```
['Background', 'Zeus']
['Background', 'BlueWhale']
['Background', 'ViolentViolet']
['Background', 'MardiGras']
['Background', 'WoodBark']
['Background', 'ViolentViolet']
['Background', 'MidnightExpress']
['Background', 'Maire']
['Background', 'Pohutukawa']
```

How do I make just one column that lists all backgrounds so it can look something like this:

```
    Background
0   Zeus
1   BlueWhale
2   ViolentViolet
3   MardiGras
4   WoodBark
5   ViolentViolet
6   MidnightExpress
7   Maire
8   Pohutukawa
```

In addition to the above, how would I also go about finding the count for each item so that it shows up as:

```
Background
Zeus - 1
BlueWhale - 1
ViolentViolet - 2
MardiGras - 1
WoodBark - 1
MidnightExpress - 1
Maire - 1
Pohutukawa - 1
```

Comment: I don't understand, isn't `df` already a dataframe with the column you want? Can you provide its content?

Comment: df shows something like this: '[['Background' 'Zeus']
 ['Body' 'Pale']
 ['Eyes' 'Watery']
 ['Clothes' 'Kurta']
 ['Head' 'HeadScarf']
 ['Mouth' 'Bandana']]
[['Background' 'BlueWhale']
 ['Body' 'Silver']
 ['Eyes' 'NoEyes']
 ['Clothes' 'VarsityJacket']
 ['Head' 'Beanie']
 ['Mouth' 'NoAccessory']]' but I would like to rearrange the dataframe where all the Backgrounds are listed under one column Background, and the same for Body, Eyes, Clothes etc.

Comment: What is `df[1]`?

Comment: df[1] outputs this '['Body' 'Pale']
['Body' 'Silver']
['Body' 'Cracked']
['Body' 'Tribal']
['Body' 'AquaHaze']
['Body' 'Silver']
['Body' 'AquaHaze']
['Body' 'TheOGO']
['Body' 'Schizophrenic']' but I would like to have one only one column Body that has Pale, Silver, Cracked, Tribal etc. listed under it

Comment: Is this a string or a list / list of lists? If is ambiguous from the formatting in comments

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(traits, orient='columns').to_numpy() is a list, but df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(traits, orient='columns') is not a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Import libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


backgrounds = []

#Get URL and extract content
class Scraper():
    page = 1
    traits = []
    

    while page != 10:
        content = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/recklesslabs/wickedcraniums/main/{}'.format(page))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')
        page = page + 1
        
        dic_list = list(map(eval, soup))
        for dic in dic_list:
            traits = dic["attributes"]

        # df = pd.DataFrame(traits)
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(traits)
        df = df[df['trait_type']=='Background']

        backgrounds.append(df['value'].values[0])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Backgrounds': backgrounds})
l1 = df['Backgrounds']
print(l1)

value_counts = df['Backgrounds'].value_counts()
l2 = [f"{key} - {value_counts[key]}" for key in value_counts.keys()]
print(l2)
```

Comment: @intermarketics. Don't use `dic_list = list(map(eval, soup))`. It's so dangerous! Use `ast.literal_eval` instead.

Comment: whats dangerous about it? if you dont mind me asking

Comment: Very true, I did not want to ruin the "practical" learning aspect . Please follow what @Corralien has mentioned.

Comment: This should give you a good understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval

Comment: Thank you. So I should be using it like this then: 'dic_list = list(map(ast.literal_eval, soup))'?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval(soup.text)['attributes']`